# PHP Transform multiple objects into one array

Tags: php, arrays, object

Whilst trying to transform multiple objects and put them into one array I unfortunately get a array-in-array result.

**The objects I would like to transform:**

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#104 (1) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "Paul"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#105 (1) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "Jenna"
  }
}
```

**My PHP:**

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($readers) ; $i++) {
    $json = json_encode($readers[$i]);    // 1          

    $data = json_decode($json, TRUE);     // 2    

    $arr = array();
    array_push($arr, $data);              // 3
}
```

**The outputs:**

```
// 1
{"name":"Paul"}{"name":"Jenna"}
```

-

```
// 2
Array
(
    [name] => Paul
)
Array
(
    [name] => Jenna
)
```

-

```
// 3
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Paul
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Jenna
        )

)
```

**Desired Outcome**

I would like to have everything merged into one array. The key is the index and the value is the name.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Paul
    [1] => Jenna
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the array of objects (`$arr`) and compile the final array (`$finArr`) with the `$val->string` value. Try this:

```
$finArr = array();
foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
  $finArr[] = $val->string;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to extract key also from array. And declare `$arr = array()` outside foreach

```
$arr = array();
for ($i=0; $i < count($readers) ; $i++) {
    $data = $readers[$i]->name;          //change this line 
    array_push($arr, $data);              // 3
}

print_r($arr);
```

Another way is you can simply use `array_column()`

```
$arr = array_column($readers,"name");
print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply iterate through the array of readers, pull out the name of each reader, and add each of their names to a numerically indexed array as you desire.

```
$names = array(); // Initialize.

foreach($readers as $reader) {
    if (!empty($reader->name)) {
        $names[] = $reader->name;
    }
}
```

---

```
print_r($names); // To see what you've got.
```

---

```
Array
(
    [0] => Paul
    [1] => Jenna
)
```